# Can getSymbols get futures data from Yahoo?

Tags: r

I tried the following code:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("GCH15.CMX",src="yahoo",from="2015-01-01")
Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GCH15.CMX&a=0&b=01&c=2015&d=2&e=12&f=2015&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=GCH15.CMX&x=.csv'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

But I got the symbol "GCH15.CMX" from Yahoo. and we can use the following link to get the information: http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=GCH15.CMX%20Interactive#%7B%22range%22%3A%225d%22%2C%22scale%22%3A%22linear%22%7D

So does `getSymbols` support getting futures data from Yahoo?

---

OK. After several trying with Yahoo, I know to get the futures data from Yahooo is impossible since Yahoo just doesn't provide the function as it with Stocks. Such a pity.... :-(

Comment: I've edited you post to clarify you want futures data and not future data, which is of course impossible!

Comment: Try doing `getSymbols("GOOG",src="yahoo",from="2015-01-01")` instead of the futures symbol.  If `GOOG` works, then you will know that the problem lies with futures data.  We can only be certain of this by looking at the `quantmod` source code for `getSymbols` to understand how it is using Yahoo's APIs.

Comment: OK. After several trying with Yahoo, I know to get the futures data from Yahooo is impossible since Yahoo just doesn't provide the function as it with Stocks. Such a pity.... :-(

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot "get the "information" from the link you provided. There is no historical data for `getSymbols` to retrieve.